# invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]

Tags: arduino-uno

With WebSocket various messages arrive.

Task:

1. Find message "setBrightness: 15"
2. Extract the value "15" from the message (the value can be any)
3. Convert this value to uint8_t

My code:

```
#include <string.h>

String payload_str = "setBrightness: 15"; // WebSocket message
const char* payload = payload_str.c_str(); // Convert string to char

const char* value; // Message value
uint8_t brightness;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  if(strncmp(payload, "setBri", 6) == 0) { // Search message
   value = strtok(payload, " ");
   value = strtok(NULL," "); // Get value (15)
   brightness = (uint8_t)atoi(value); // Convert to uint8_t 
  }
}

void loop() {}
```

Compilling error:

> error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
>
> error:   initializing argument 1 of 'char* strtok(char*, const char*)' [-fpermissive]

Maybe I'm doing it completely wrong and not safe. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtok` modifies the char buffer entered as first parameter. It replaces the delimiters with terminating zeros. To parse a constant string with `strtok`, you must first copy it into a working char buffer.

For your test you can initialize a char array as in following example.

```
char payload[] = "setBrightness: 15";

uint8_t brightness;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  if(strncmp(payload, "setBri", 6) == 0) { // Search message
   strtok(payload, " ");
   const char* tok = strtok(NULL," "); // Get value (15)
   brightness = (uint8_t) atoi(tok); // Convert to uint8_t
  }
}

void loop() {}
```

---

if you know the 'name' part of the name:value string, you can skip it for `atoi` this way:

`brightness = (uint8_t) atoi(payload + strlen("setBrightness: "));`

(`strlen("setBrightness: "` will be evaluated at compile time to a constant number)

```
const char payload[] = "setBrightness: 15";

uint8_t brightness;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  if(strncmp(payload, "setBri", 6) == 0) { // Search message
     brightness = (uint8_t) atoi(payload + strlen("setBrightness: ")); // Convert to uint8_t
  }
}

void loop() {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will try today and say the result.